# Can't insert current date to new row

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (user_name, user_password, user_email, user_joindate) 
          VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', CURDATE())";


$result=mysqli_query($currentConnection, $query) or die ("Could not insert into database.");
```

It connects to the database just fine and It's hitting the or die error (could not insert).

user_joindate type is ''DATE'' because I don't want irrelevant hour times. Already tried now() and current_timestamp, doesn't work.

edit: the problem is in the user_joindate query because when I remove it, the whole query works, despite the user_joindate receving a bunch of zeros.

Comment: set user_joindate type is varchar than try

Comment: There is a mysql data type just for that - datetime

Comment: Please give us your table structure/schema

Comment: You're a siting duck for SQL Injection attacks, you should always use prepared statements when dealing with user submitted data

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store current date than set default value is CURDATE() function in insert query
like

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
OrderId int NOT NULL,
ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
)
```

insert query

INSERT INTO Orders (ProductName) VALUES ('Jarlsberg Cheese')

Comment: @Hiago Serpa try this query other wise set value in phpmyadmin in localhost

Comment: Tried datetime with DATE type, datetime with VARCHAR (255) type, curdate() with VARCHAR (255) type, nothing works.

Comment: bro try this query for creating table than automatically insert the current date in table

Comment: apply curdate() default value in user_joindate field using query ya phpmyadmin than run this query.  $query = "INSERT INTO user (user_name, user_password, user_email) 
          VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";

Comment: Dude I'm not sure this is the correct approach for the problem, creating an entire table just to fetch one row and deliver to the other table? I'm trying to understand why my code is wrong when I can't see any problem. Maybe it would work if I set the type of user_joindate to ''DATETIME'', but I DON'T WANT the hours/minutes/seconds. Just the date, what ''DATE'' was supposed to provide me that.

Comment: Tried this, and says its invalid: ALTER TABLE user ALTER COLUMN user_joindate SET DEFAULT '{CURDATE()}';

Comment: ALTER TABLE myTable 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME
    DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR myColumn

Comment: try this query ALTER TABLE user 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME
    DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR user_joindate

Answer (score 0):

Can you write here an error message from mysql? If you don't know how to get error message just rewrite your code like this:

```
if(!mysqli_query($currentConnection, $query)) {
    echo mysqli_error($currentConnection);
}
```

Without an error message nobody is not able to answer you correctly

---

According to the error output that you paste to the comment, your query tries to insert the same value for the unique field twice. It seems your user_id field is primary but not auto-increment. Just do it an auto-increment than try to insert again. The user_id field will be set a unique value each time.

Comment: There is an error message, everything inside the parenthesis: or die ("Could not insert into database."). And it specifically says the it's in the insert query part.

Comment: This message is your custom message. Thats why you cannot understand the concrete reason of fault. You need to know what says database about this problem :) For this reason you have to get database error message to discover the real reason of error

Comment: Tried what you said, and the error is: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'         I tought I already set that, how do I confirm or manually edit the user_id?

Comment: Very well. Now everythink is clear :) As you see you are trying to insert the same value again. It would be better if you make your primary key indexed user_id column auto-increment. Than you don't need to give a value to this column, it will take a unique value automatically. Or you can rewrite your sql query like that: 
$query = "REPLACE INTO user (user_id, user_name, user_password, user_email, user_joindate) VALUES (uuid(), '$username', '$password', '$email', CURDATE())";
If my answer was usefull vote up please ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple you just change data type of user_joindate field and set  **TIMESTAMP** data type and also not need to insert value when you add record 
like this way

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (user_name, user_password, user_email) 
          VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";


$result=mysqli_query($currentConnection, $query) or die ("Could not insert into database.");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the database error you got from the unsuccessful saving of `CURDATE()` into your table, you can either alter the column that's causing the error or you manually provide a value for that to avoid duplication.

If you want to change your `user_id` column, you can do this:

```
//this is incremental
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE user_id user_id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

If you want providing an id manually, make sure your `user_id` datatype is in **char/varchar/...** and your query be like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name, user_password, user_email, user_joindate) VALUES (uuid(), '$username', '$password', '$email', CURDATE())";
```

> And just a warning not to use mysql_* now for it is [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)
>   officially as of PHP 5.5 and has been removed entirely as of PHP 7.0.
>   Try using the latest ones like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)/[Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php) to avoid having
>   problems in the  future.